# Hiding WooCommerce Checkout Button with javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress, storefront

I am trying to hide the **Place Order** Button on my WooCommerce Site, but the behavior seems to be overridden by some other script because the button would hide and then it would reappear.

I am using the **storefront 1.5** theme and **Wordpress 4.3**

JS Loading Code :

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'order_summary_script', 9999); //last script to load
function order_summary_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('order-summary', get_bloginfo('stylesheet_directory') . '/assets/js/order-summary.js', array('jquery'), '1.0.0', true);
}
```

Hiding Code:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
    //hide place order button on checkout page
    $('input[name=woocommerce_checkout_place_order]').hide();
});
```

[image]

**Update:**

Even if I added the script to the footer per Dev Danidhariya suggestion ( which means it's the last script ) it still doesn't fix it. [Wordpress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Javascript) mention below:

> JavaScript cannot be added to post content without a special WordPress
>   Plugin that removes the filters that prevent unwanted code within the
>   post content area, for the protection of the user.

Could this be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Add This code in Your Active theme **Footer.php**

```
<script>
    jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {
        //hide place order button on checkout page
        $('input[name=woocommerce_checkout_place_order]').hide();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You'll want a closing square bracket in that selector.

Comment: thanks, it works, but why didn't my code work? What script is overriding my action?

Comment: your Script Run Before Default Property.So Your Script is Overwrite,

Comment: Is there a way to make the enqueue script work the same way? Because this way my script would be fragmented.

Comment: Turns out it didn't work. At first I just added your code to the footer without anything else, it works but I forgot to include the storefront footer's code. When I include the footer's code it failed again.

Comment: add this code in footer.php before </body> tag.and check.